# cc2650 disable sensor in app android

Tags: java, android

How to disable the sensors using the characteristic configuration in project with the cc2650 sensortag that enables and disables sensors for infrequent measurement.

The cc2650wiki is reported that this is possible writing the value 0x00 in the characteristic configuration and i found in the GenericBluetoothProfile.java the method disableService that seems to do what i was looking for:

```
public void disableService () {
    int error = mBTLeService.writeCharacteristic(this.configC, (byte)0x00);
    if (error != 0) {
        if (this.configC != null)
            printError("Sensor disable failed: ",this.configC,error);
    }
    this.isConfigured = false;
}
```

I tried to use this method in a function of the deviceActivity that i inserted to write in a file the data of the sensors but when i try to connect the sensortag the app shuts down:

```
public void LogToCSV(Map<String, String> data)
    {
        for (GenericBluetoothProfile p : mProfiles) {
            p.disableService();

        }
```

Also without the instruction in the cycle for the app doesn't work.
How to fix this?